# How to identify and remove child folders in a list of folders?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Let's say I have a list of folders in an array:

```
c:\aaa\bbb
d:\aaa\bbb
c:\aaa\bbb\ccc
c:\aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd
```

My program will carry out some operations recursively for each objects in those folders. But as you can see, some folders in this array have parent-child relationship. So I should remove the nested folders in this array before my process. For the above example, `c:\aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd` and `c:\aaa\bbb\ccc` will be removed as they are nested in `c:\aaa\bbb`. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first sort the array in ascending order and visit each of the folders in that order. Then keep track of a "parent" folder, which starts out with an invalid name:

```
 sort folders
 parent = '>'
 result = []
 for each folder in folders:  
     if folder does not start with parent followed by a slash: 
         # keep folder, and remember it as potential parent
         append folder to result
         parent = folder
```

Here is a JavaScript code example:

```js
var folders = [
    'c:\\aaa\\bbb',
    'd:\\aaa\\bbb',
    'c:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc',
    'c:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\ddd'
];

folders.sort();
let parent = '>';
let result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    if (folders[i].indexOf(parent + '\\') != 0) {
        result.push(folders[i]); // keep it
        parent = folders[i]; // and remember this as potential parent 
    }
}

// Display result
console.log(result.join('\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to solve your problem, but it is some light at the process to find it.

First of all, **the code**.

```
/**
 * Created by Zack at 14/January/2017
 */
public class ChildPathRemover {

    private final Node mRoot = new Node();

    /**
     *
     * @param path
     * @return True if the directory was added, False if is a child directory
     */
    public boolean add(String path) {
        Node currNode = mRoot;

        String[] parts = path.split(Pattern.quote(File.separator));
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            // contains
            Node nextNode = currNode.subNodes.get(parts[i]);

            if (nextNode != null) {
                // Already has a parent
                if (nextNode.isLeaf) {
                    return false;
                } // Process the nextNode
                else {
                    currNode = nextNode;
                }
            } // Reached the end, so we a good to add new path
            else {
                for (int k = i; k < parts.length; k++) {
                    Node newNode = new Node();
                    currNode.subNodes.put(parts[k], newNode);
                    currNode = newNode;
                }

                currNode.isLeaf = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // TODO: if the parent were not added first, you will need to rebuild the paths, based on the
        // Nodes and then call the Remove Listener

        return true;
    }

    private static class Node {

        boolean isLeaf = false;
        HashMap<String, Node> subNodes = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public interface RemoveListener {

        void pathRemoved(String path);
    }

    /**
     * Call this method to remove the child paths
     *
     * @param paths
     */
    public static void removeChildPath(List<String> paths) {
        // Sort by the length of the path
        Collections.sort(paths, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
            }
        });


        ChildPathRemover cpr = new ChildPathRemover();

        Iterator<String> itr = paths.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            if (!cpr.add(itr.next())) {
                itr.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Example of how to use.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    paths.add("d:\\aaa\\bbb");
    paths.add("c:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc");
    paths.add("c:\\aaa\\bbb\\ccc\\ddd");
    paths.add("c:\\aaa\\bbb");

    removeChildPath(paths);

    for (String path : paths) {
        System.out.println("path = " + path);
    }
}
```

This example will produce

```
path = d:\aaa\bbb
path = c:\aaa\bbb
```

---

**Explanation**

The idea here is to simulate a tree.

So first we add all the parent folders; this is done by sorting the array by the length of the paths.

Then, every time we add a path with success, it will be marked as leaf. When we try to add another path and it is "bigger", the code will know that it is a child, so we delete it.

---

EDIT:

Sorry... I did not see that this question was **not** marked as a Java question...